# Call Oracle Stored Procedure with Char Out Parameter errors with PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: c#, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net, enterprise-library-6

I have the following Oracle Stored Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE SP_ITEMEXISTS(pID IN NUMBER, pExists OUT CHAR) IS
BEGIN
        select CASE count(*) WHEN 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END into pExists from items where id = pID;
END SP_ITEMEXISTS;
```

I'm calling it from Enterprise Library 6.0 with ODP.NET with the following code:

```
    public bool ItemExists(int itemID)
    {
        string procedureName = "SP_ItemExists";
        var database = new DatabaseProviderFactory().CreateDefault();
        bool returnValue = false;

        using (OracleCommand command = (OracleCommand)database.GetStoredProcCommand(procedureName))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("pID", OracleDbType.Int32, itemID, ParameterDirection.Input);
            command.Parameters.Add("pExists", OracleDbType.Char, ParameterDirection.Output);

            using (OracleDataReader reader = ((OracleDataReaderWrapper)database.ExecuteReader(command)).InnerReader)
            {
                char exists = reader.GetChar("pExists");

                if (exists.ToString().ToUpper() == "Y")
                    returnValue = true;
                else
                    returnValue = false;
            }
        }

        return returnValue;

    }
```

I receive the following error:
**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_ITEMEXISTS'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored**

I have other stored procedures that I can call successfully, but the others have a refcursor OUT parameter. How do I call it when the OUT type is Char?

Comment: Does it work when you run `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); char exists = command.Parameters[2].Value;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExecuteReader is used only for RefCursor as you found out already. Use `database.ExecuteNonQuery()` for calling a procedure or function.
Read out return values with `command.Parameters("pExists").Value`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm receiving a new error and created a new question for that error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20525707/enterprise-library-odp-net-call-returns-ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-erro